# How to resize an image in Java with OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv, image-resizing

After cropping an image how can I resize it?

```
Mat croppedimage = cropImage( image, rect );
Mat resizeimage = croppedimage.resize( any dimension ); //need to change this line
```

Comment: Header says "how to resize image with opencv" but answer describes to resize a "cropped image" not a Java File or Java Buffered Image or something else. So my question is "how to get Mat object out of BufferedImage or at least File?"

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think, you want [this](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#resize(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Size)).

e.g.

```
Mat croppedimage = cropImage(image,rect);
Mat resizeimage = new Mat();
Size sz = new Size(100,100);
Imgproc.resize( croppedimage, resizeimage, sz );
```

Comment: What should I put for the size if i want the application to calculate the size. Eg. fx = 0.5 and fy = 0.5. Tried putting 0 and Size() for dsize but doesnt work.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to **scale** an image using OpenCV java then do the following:

```
  import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.*;
  import static org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread;
```

Main code:

```
   Mat src  =  imread("imageName.jpg");
   Mat resizeimage = new Mat();
   Size scaleSize = new Size(300,200);
   resize(src, resizeimage, scaleSize , 0, 0, INTER_AREA);
```

For downscaling it is recommended to use: INTER_AREA and for upscaling use INTER_CUBIC

For more details: [OpenCV Ref for Resize](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d)

Answer (score 4):

1. Please read manual for c++ method [Resize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize) it's the same to java.
2. You can choose a type of interpolation. In some cases it's important for a best result.

   ```
   Mat croppedImage = cropImage(image,rect);
   Mat resizeImage = new Mat(anyHeight, anyWidth, croppedImage.type());   
   int interpolation = Imgproc.INTER_CUBIC;   
   Imgproc.resize(croppedImage, resizeImage, resizeImage.size(), 0, 0, interpolation );
   ```